# Value cannot be cast from ReadableNativeMap to double

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, variables, marker

I have a custom marker image and want to use a variable for the opacity of the image. I doing the following and gettin this error "Value for opacity cannot be cast from ReadableNativeMap to double"

```
var status=1;

  <MapView.Marker
         key={marker.latitude}
         coordinate={{ latitude: marker.latitude, longitude: marker.longitude }} 
         onPress={() => this.props.Quiz2(marker.latitude, marker.longitude)} >
    <View><Image source={require('../assets/icons/quiz.png')} style={{ width: 40, height: 40,opacity:status}}/></View>
</MapView.Marker>
```

[image]

Comment: use `status = 1.0` instead.

Comment: did you try to use `Animated.Image` instead of `Image`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `<Animated.*>` e.g.

For `<View>` use `<Animated.View>`

For `<Image>` use `<Animated.Image>`

And so on. React Native will understand Animated.Value if it's used in `Animated.*` component.