# SetState called many times

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a problem concerning the display of My DateTimePicker Widget !! I have written the code below and this error is occured **Maximum update depth exceeded This can happen when a  component repeatedly calls setState** I dont see any infinte code in my own . I defined `SetState` in 2 parts of my code, when i run it ,It displays a big calendar which is set to a date which is not the initial one in my `state` above !! few seconds later it dsplays the error ..! 
I have defined within my code , 3 other `view` which are not mentionned during the display onmy the big `calendar` is displayed !!

```
constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state={
     selectedLabel:'4 mois',
     value : parseInt('2020-06-20')
                }

Show (value){
        this.setState({selectedLabel :value});
    }

render () {

                       <Picker style={{marginLeft:10,width:260}} 
                             selectedValue={this.state.selectedLabel} onValueChange={this.Show()}>
                            <Picker.Item label= "1 semaine"></Picker.Item>
                            <Picker.Item label=" 15 jours "></Picker.Item>
                            <Picker.Item label=" 1 mois "></Picker.Item>
                        </Picker>


                        <DateTimePicker
                             style={{width:200}}
                             mode="date"
                             value={this.state.value}
                             display="calendar" 
                             minimumDate={new Date((2300, 10, 20))}
                             onChange={(value)=>this.setState({value})}
                         />
```

Comment: onValueChange={this.Show()} <-- this is wrong , change it to onValueChange={this.Show}, you are calling this.Show() on loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are calling the setState everytime the component renders. Change your Picker handler with the following code:

```
onValueChange={(value) => this.Show(value)}
```

Comment: This way is wrong too, if you really want to use  the arrow function you must do like so : onValueChange={value => this.Show(value)}

Comment: @CevaComic But i Have another problem ````Value for value cannot be cast from ReadableNativeMap to Double ````

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54272759/value-cannot-be-cast-from-readablenativemap-to-double